# nginx reverse proxy: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS but second site is working

Tags: nginx, webserver, nginx-reverse-proxy, ubuntu-22.04

i'm relatively new to linux. My server is running Ubuntu 22.04 and i got a little problem here in my nginx configuration. I set up a reverse proxy (nginx) in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/reverse-proxy.conf` and wrote this into the file:

```
server {
        if ($host = domain.de) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.de;
        return 404;
}


server {
        server_name domain.de;

                listen 443 ssl http2;
                listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.de/privkey.pem;
                include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
                ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

                proxy_buffering off;
                server_tokens off;

        location ^~ /swagger {
                return 404;
        }

        location / {

        root    /var/www/html/domain.de;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index-one.html ;

                proxy_pass      http://127.0.1.1;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
                proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
                proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
#                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_CF_Connecting_IP;

                add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin-when-cross-origin';
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; preload" always;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

        }

}


server {
        if ($host = second.domain.de) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        listen 80;
        server_name second.domain.de;
        return 404;
}



server {
        server_name second.domain.de;

                listen 443 ssl http2;
                listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/second.domain.de/fullchain.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/second.domain.de/privkey.pem;
                include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
                ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

                proxy_buffering off;
                server_tokens off;

        location ^~ /swagger {
                return 404;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass      http://192.168.198.40:8096;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
                proxy_set_header Range $http_range;
                proxy_set_header If-Range $http_if_range;
#                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $http_CF_Connecting_IP;

                add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin-when-cross-origin';
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552000; preload" always;
                add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
                add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;

        }

}
```

The second domain is a streaming service called emby and it works, the first domain is a website i want to host and it is based in `/var/www/html/domain.de`. The directive `/var/www/html/domain.de` is owned by www-data.

This config gives me an ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on domain.de but the second.domain.de is working fine. Why? What am i doing wrong here?

When i change the ip address in the first domain from `127.0.2.1` to `192.168.198.40` the same error occurs. When i add a port to the address like `127.0.2.1:8080;` or `192.168.198.40:8080;` i get a 502 Bad Gateway error message.
The second domain is working fine in all constellations but i can't get the first domain to work and i don't know how to fix this.
I hope anybody can help me out here. :)